# How to peek a tokio TcpStream from a TcpListener?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I am writing a server using rustls and hyper and wish to peek and then parse the TcpStream to then accept the corresponding `tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor` I want. However, this leads me to use both async and non async functions (`tokio::net::TcpStream::peek` and `tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor::accept`) on the stream, which as been causing me trouble. Simply adding an async block for the `peek` function gives me an `` "unused implementer of `core::future::future::Future` that must be used" `` error and changing `move` to `async move` does not work.

I'm wondering if there is some way to get around this, perhaps by not using `and_then()`?

```
// Dependencies: futures-util = "0.3.1", rustls = "0.18"
// tokio = {version = "0.2", features = ["full"]}, tokio-rustls = "0.14.0"
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio_rustls::server::TlsStream;
use tokio_rustls::TlsAcceptor;
use std::{sync, io};
use futures_util::{
    future::TryFutureExt,
    stream::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt},
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn run_server() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>{
    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", 8000);
    let mut tcp = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await?;

    let tls_config = sync::Arc::new(rustls::ServerConfig::new(rustls::NoClientAuth::new()));
    let tls_acceptor = TlsAcceptor::from(tls_config);

    let mut v = vec![0u8; 16 * 1024];

    // main focus of question
    let incoming_tls_stream = tcp
        .incoming()
        .map_err(|e| error(format!("Incoming failed: {:?}", e)))
        .and_then(move |mut s: TcpStream| {
            let n: usize = s.peek(&mut v).await.unwrap();
            println!("{:}", n);
            // parse something from stream
            let parsed = do_something(&v[..n]);
            println!("{:}", parsed);

            tls_acceptor.accept(s).map_err(|e| {
                println!("Client-connection error...");
                error(format!("TLS Error: {:?}", e))
            })
        })
        .boxed();

    // ...
    return Ok(());
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = run_server() {
        eprintln!("FAILED: {}", e);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn error(err: String) -> io::Error {
    io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err)
}

fn do_something(bytes: &[u8]) -> &str {
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: The `async` block isn't used though. It isn't returned by the closure, and nothing it produces is used either.

Comment: @PeterHall you're right, but I'm not sure how to correctly use the block or if it is the best way to solve my problem. Edited the code to simplify my question.

Comment: You have other problems too, like sharing `v` and `s` across an async boundary.

Comment: Yes, sharing s is precisely the problem I'm looking to solve.

Comment: Then you need to make these variables sharable. e.g. wrap them in an `Arc<Mutex>`. Or else force the task to be run in the same thread with a [`LocalSet`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html).

Comment: Maybe you want to use the [`poll_peek`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.poll_peek) method instead of `peek`, which waits for the stream to be ready to read?